# Datatables - Data set across 3 tables evenly - single controls

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatable

I'm using the Datatables JQuery plugin and am looking to do the following:

I have a set of data, lets say 350 records.  No matter the size, I want to pull the records in 3 even batches (or as even as possible), and have them display in 3 tables, on one page.  There should be no pagination.  And I want sorting on one table, to effect sorting on the others.

I've tried dynamically generating tables based on the number of records in the database, and then creating a `for loop`.  And the display is controlled by the `LIMIT` parameter in MySQL.  The problem is, if table 2 is supposed to display records 51 - 100, I'm able to accomplish this, but it still displays it as a subset of data:  as in, if I hit 'sort by name', it sorts in reference to the other 200 records, and not within it's allotted 50.

Is there perhaps a simpler way of doing this?  Here's what I've tried:

jQuery.getJSON( templateDir + "/includes/_shelf_record_check.php", function( data ) {
        shelfTotalRecords = data.total;

```
var recordsPerTable = 40;
var numberOfTables = Math.ceil(shelfTotalRecords / recordsPerTable);

for(var i=1; i<=numberOfTables; i++) {
    if (i == 1)
        var startRecord = 0;
    else
        var startRecord = ((i-1) * recordsPerTable);


    jQuery.getJSON( templateDir + "/includes/_records_for_shelf_table.php?startRecord="+startRecord+"&recordsPerTable="+recordsPerTable, function( recordData ) {

    var shelfTable = "shelfTable"+i;
    var HTMLTableID = 'shelf-table'+i;
        jQuery('#shelf-table-page').append("<table id='"+HTMLTableID+"' class='display dataTable shelf'>" +
            "<thead>" +
                "<tr>"+
                    "<th></th>"+
                    "<th>Order</th>"+
                    "<th>First Name</th>"+
                    "<th>Last Name</th>"+
                    "<th>Shelf</th>"+
                    "<th>Status</th>"+
                "</tr>"+
            "</thead>"+
            "<tbody>"+
                "<tr>"+
                    "<td colspan='4' class='dataTables_empty'>Loading data from server</td>"+
                "</tr>" +
            "</tbody>"+
            "<tfoot>"+
                "<tr>"+
                    "<th></th>"+
                    "<th>Order</th>"+
                    "<th>First Name</th>"+
                    "<th>Last Name</th>"+
                    "<th>Shelf</th>"+
                    "<th>Status</th>"+
                "</tr>"+
                "</tfoot>"  +   
        "</table>");


     /* DataTable for the Shelf Table Page */
      shelfTable = jQuery('#'+HTMLTableID).dataTable( {
         "bPaginate": false,  
         "iDisplayLength": recordsPerTable,
         "iDisplayStart": startRecord,
                 "bProcessing": true,
             "bServerSide": true,
         "bDestroy": true,
         "bJQueryUI": true,
         "bFilter": false,
         "bAutoWidth": false,
         "oLanguage": {
          "sInfoFiltered": " (_MAX_ total records)"
          },
         "bLengthChange": false,
             "sAjaxSource": templateDir + "/includes/_get_shelf_table.php?recordIds="+recordData.recordIds,
         "aaSorting": [[ 3, "asc" ]],
          "aoColumns": [     
            { "sName": "id", "bVisible": false },
            { "sName": "order_number"},
            { "sName": "first_name"},
            { "sName": "last_name"},
            { "sName": "shelf" },
            { "sName": "status_id" }
         ]

      });
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I solved this using the "fnServerParams" parameter, which allows you to pass data to to an Ajax source, for further filtering

Answer (score 0):

do your for loop first to split the data into 3 different arrays, then pass those separate sources to jquery.  or did I miss something? otherwise if you can store the "ids" of the first results and then send those ids on each query,.

Comment: ive tried the latter suggestion, but for whatever reason, was having trouble sending them with each query.  I was trying to send the returned JSON object, in the URL to the `_get_shelf_table.php` script, but I think it's incorrectly formatted perhaps, as it never seems to reach the PHP script

Comment: I don't know your api but maybe records per table isn't the right way. it should be something like "endrecord"

Comment: I don't think Datatables has an 'endrecord' sort of functionality, but I'll double check